A group homomorphism $G\to H$ between finitely generated groups is a quasi-isometry iff the kernel is finite and the image has finite index in $H$
this question is already partially answered here: When does group homomorphism imply quasi-isometric, but there is no full solution and I struggle to fill in some details.
First, here is the equivalent characterization of quasi-isometry that I'll be using (From Clara Löh's Geometric Group Theory: An Introduction):

A map
$f \colon X \to  Y$ between metric spaces $(X, d_X )$ and $(Y, d_Y )$ is a quasi-isometry
if and only if it is a quasi-isometric embedding with quasi-dense image; a
map $f \colon X → Y$ has quasi-dense image if there is a constant $c ∈ R_{>0}$ such
that
$$∀y∈Y, \quad ∃x∈X, \quad d_Y (f (x), y) ≤ c.$$
The map $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding if there are constants $c ∈ R_{>0}$
and $b ∈ R_{>0}$ such that f is a $(c, b)$-quasi-isometric embedding, i.e.,
$$∀x,x′∈X \qquad
\frac 1c · d_X (x, x′) − b ≤ d_Y
(f (x), f (x′)) ≤ c · d_X (x, x′) + b.$$

If $f\colon G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then the condition that $f$ has to satisfy for it to be a $(c,b)$-quasi-isometric embedding (with respect to the word metrics corresponding to finite generating sets $S \subset G$ and $T \subset H$) reads:
$$∀g \in G \qquad
\frac 1c · \left| g \right|_S − b ≤ \left| f(g) \right|_T ≤ c · \left| g \right|_S + b,$$
where $\left| g \right|_S \equiv d_{G,S}(g,e)$ is the word length of $g \in G$ with respect to the finite generating set $S$.
What I have been able to show (using the hints in When does group homomorphism imply quasi-isometric) is that the condition that the image has finite index in $H$ is equivalent to $f$ having quasi-dense image in $H$:

If $\text{im}(f)$ has finite index in $H$, then there is a finite subset $A \subset H$ such that $\text{im}(f) \cdot A = H$. Now let $c > 0$ denote the maximal word length in $H$ (wrt $T$) of the elements in $A$. Then for each $h \in H$, there exist $a \in A$ and $g \in G$ such that $h =  f(g) \cdot a$ and then $$d_{H,T}(f(g),h) = d_{H,T}(f(g), f(g)\cdot a) = d_{H,T}(e, a) \leq c.$$
If $f$ has quasi-dense image in $H$ (with constant $c >0$), then define the ball $$A = \{ a \in H \,:\, \left| a \right|_T \leq c \}.$$ Because $H$ is finitely generated, this finite radius ball is finite. Now, in a similar way as above, it is not so hard to show that $\text{im}(f) \cdot A = H$. Indeed, for a given $h \in H$, by quasi-density we can find $g \in G$ such that $d_{H,T}(f(g),h) \leq c,$ and because $$d_{H,T}(f(g),h) = \left|f(g) \cdot h^{-1} \right|_T$$ this shows that indeed $f(g) \cdot h^{-1} \in A$.

Next, the answer (and comments) in When does group homomorphism imply quasi-isometric hint that the condition that $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding is equivalent to $\ker (f)$ being finite. One direction is not so hard: $f$ being a quasi-isometric embedding implies that $\ker(f)$ is finite:

If $f \colon G \to H$ is a quasi-isometric embedding, then for each $g \in \ker(f)$ we have $$\frac 1c · \left| g \right|_S − b ≤ \left| f(g) \right|_T = 0 \implies \left| g \right|_S \leq bc.$$ Hence, $\ker(f)$ is bounded wrt to the word metric in $G$. Since $G$ is finitely generated, this implies that $\ker(f)$ is finite.

But for the other direction I get stuck. I.e., I cannot show that $\ker(f)$ being finite implies that $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding, save for the 'obvious' upper bound which follows from the triangle inequality (and for which I did not need the kernel) $$\left| f(g) \right|_T \leq m \cdot \left| g\right|_S$$ where $$ m:= \max \{ \left|f(s)\right|_T \mid s \in S \cup S^{-1}\}.$$
It could also be that in this missing direction, you also need to use that $\text{im}(f)$ has finite index in $H$, but I do not immediately see how. Thanks in advance!

If $ker (f)$ is finite, then $f$ factorise through $ p: G\to G/kerf(f)$, but $p$ is a quasi isometry. So you can assume that $f$ is injective. The ilage of $f$ is a subgroup of finite index $K<H$. T he embedding $K\to H$ is also a quasi isometry (as K$ is of finite inded. Does this help?

@Thomas yes, thank you, I've filled in the details as an answer to this post

It's not generally true that $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding if its kernel is finite. For a good counterexample, take the codomain to be the solvable Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,a) = \langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^2\rangle$, and consider the homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z \to BS(1,a)$ given by $f(n) = a^n$. This is actually a group theoretic embedding, but it is not a quasi-isometric embedding, because $f(a^{2^n}) = t^n a t^{-n}$.
So you will also have to use something else that you know about $f$, besides that it's kernel is finite, to derive that $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding. And you can do this using that $f$ has quasi-dense image. Here's a few details.
As suggested in the hints, you can break this problem into two steps, by factoring $f$ as
$$G \mapsto K = G / \text{ker}(f) \mapsto H
$$
The effect is that the problem is reduced to two separate special cases about a homomrophism $f : G \to H$ between finitely generated groups:
Case 1: If $f$ is surjective and has finite kernel then $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding.
Case 2: If $f$ is injective and has finite index image (i.e. if it has quasi-dense image) then $f$ is a quasi-isometric embedding.
In both cases, given $g,g' \in G$, choose a word geodesic between $f(g)$ and $f(g')$, say
$$f(g) = h_0, h_1, \ldots, h_L = f(g'), \qquad L = d_h(f(g),f(g')) \qquad h_{i+1}=h_i s_i
$$
where the $s_i$'s are all in the chosen finite generating set for $H$. We have to prove
$$d_G(g,g') \le K L + C
$$
for some constants $K \ge 1$, $C \ge 0$.
Since you say you are having trouble only in the Case 1, then I'll give a proof just for that case. The key missing idea is to make good use of the additional case 1 assumption that $f$ is surjective. This assumption allows us to choose elements $g_i  \in  f^{-1}(h_i)$ for each $i$. We can furthermore make our choices so that $g_0 = g$ and $g_L = g'$, and so we get a sequence
$$g = g_0,g_1,\ldots,g_L=g'
$$
So now all we have to do is to bound $d_G(g_i,g_{i+1}) \le K$ independently of $i$, and it will follow that $d_G(g,g') \le KL$.
That means we have to bound $g_i^{-1}g_{i+1}$ independently of $i$. But
$$f(g_i^{-1} g_{i+1}) = h_i^{-1} h_{i+1} = s_i
$$
So we just have to find a uniform bound for the word norms of those elements $\gamma \in G$ such that $f(\gamma) = s_i$ for some $i$. But
$$A = \bigcup_i f^{-1}(s_i)
$$
is a finite subset of $G$ --- because the kernel of $f$ is finite and the $s_i$'s are varying over a fixed finite generating set for $H$ --- therefore the word norms for elements of $A$ are uniformly bounded.

Thank you, you beat me to answering my own question in a matter of seconds! So if I get it right, in my answer I did case 1 using Svarc-Milnor, correct?

That's more-or-less right. I'm just going straight at the troubling case that you mentioned in your post, and more-or-less extracting the precise portion of the Milnor-Švarc argument which addresses that case.

Thanks to @Thomas's comment, I think I can fill in the details of the argument.
First, we can assume that $f$ is injective. Indeed, $f$ factors through $G/\ker f$ so there is an injective homomorphism $\tilde f\colon  G/\ker f \longrightarrow H$ such that $f = \tilde f \circ p$ where $p$ is the canonical projection $G \longrightarrow G/\ker f$. Since $p$ is a quasi-isometry (this can be proved by letting $G$ act on $G/\ker f$ and applying the Švarc-Milnor lemma), it now suffices to show that the injective homomorphism $\tilde f \colon G/\ker f \longrightarrow H$ is a quasi-isometry, as a composition of quasi-isometries is a quasi-isometry.
So if $f$ is injective, by restricting the codomain, it defines an isomorphism $f' \colon G \cong \text{im } f$ and hence a (quasi-)isometry with respect to the finite generating sets $S\subset G$ and $f(S)\subset \text{im } f$. We also know that there is a finite set of generators $T' \subset \text{im }f$ to be found such that the inclusion $i\colon \text{im }f \longrightarrow H$ is a quasi-isometry, because $\text{im } f$ has finite index. It follows that $f$ is a quasi-isometry, as it can be realised as a composition of quasi-isometries $$(G,d_S) \longrightarrow (\text{im }f, d_{f(S)}) \longrightarrow (\text{im }f, d_{T'}) \longrightarrow (H, d_T).$$ (The identity map of a group is a bilipschitz equivalence (and hence a quasi-isometry) with respect to any two different word metrics coming from finite generating sets.)
